# python: Assign multiple values to a dictionary key and replace a column values with the keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains values that fall into the same categories but have different names. I was thinking of creating a dictionary with a key assigned to multiple values and then replace the values in the column with the key. Here is what I have and what I want to achieve.

Define dictionary

```
sspdict={'Eva':["M-EV", "G-EV"],'Re Sci': ['G-RESC', 'M-RESC', 'S-RESC', 'D-RESC'], 'Ed':['G-PO' , 'M-PO'], 'Global':['C-GCC', 'D-GCLA', 'C-LACL']}
```

Dataset:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
12    No     M-EV
22    Yes    G-EV
23    Yes    G-RESC
35    No     M-PO
34    Yes    D-GCLA
46    No     S-RESC
89    No     G-PO
90    Yes    C-GCC
```

Desired outcome

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
12    No     Eva
22    Yes    Eva
23    Yes    Re Sci
35    No     Ed
34    Yes    Global
46    No     Re Sci
89    No     Ed
90    Yes    Global
```

Can you please kindly help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this one-liner:

```
df.assign(Col3 = df['Col3'].apply(lambda x: [key for key, value in sspdict.items() if x in value][0]))
```

Or let's use a generator:

```
df.assign(Col3 = df['Col3'].apply(lambda x: next(key for key, value in sspdict.items() if x in value)))
```

Output:

```
   Col1 Col2    Col3
0    12   No     Eva
1    22  Yes     Eva
2    23  Yes  Re Sci
3    35   No      Ed
4    34  Yes  Global
5    46   No  Re Sci
6    89   No      Ed
7    90  Yes  Global
```

Comment: Beautiful one-liner. Did the job better than I thought. Thanks heaps Scott

Comment: I tried to use the one-liner on another dataset, but it generates this error: IndexError: list index out of range. Do you know what might cause this? Also what is the reason to use [0] in the appy method inside the one-liner? Thanks heaps

Comment: [0] Is the get the value from the list.  Inside the apply, you are using list comprehension, so you create a list, to get that first value from that list, you follow it with [0].

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you have any idea what might go wrong that generates the error? The code runs without [0] but obviously not in the form that I need.

Comment: Sorry if m question was not clear enough. I am referring to the on-liner only. The generator also result in an error of a different type. I copy/paste the error from the one-liner in my next comment, maybe it helps more to spot the source of the error

Comment: File "C:\Users\omonfared\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2355, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx", line 1569, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66440)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Omido, I am sorry I can not replicate your error with the given dataset.  May you could reproduce a dataset that would so that error.

Comment: I guess I made a stupid mistake. Some of the data that I had in my column did not have any value in the dictionary. that's why it was giving index out of range. Thanks anyway for offering help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change the `sspdict` data structure to simplify things and probably increase performance if `sspdict` is not bigger than the input dataset. It could be something like this:

```
dataset = '''Col1  Col2  Col3
12    No     M-EV
22    Yes    G-EV
23    Yes    G-RESC
35    No     M-PO
34    Yes    D-GCLA
46    No     S-RESC
89    No     G-PO
90    Yes    C-GCC
'''

sspdict = {'Eva':["M-EV", "G-EV"],'Re Sci': ['G-RESC', 'M-RESC', 'S-RESC', 'D-RESC'], 'Ed':['G-PO' , 'M-PO'], 'Global':['C-GCC', 'D-GCLA', 'C-LACL']}

lookup_dict = {value: key for key, values in sspdict.items() for value in values}
result = ''
for line in dataset.splitlines()[1:]:
    key = line.split()[2]
    result += line.rstrip(key) + lookup_dict[key] + '\n'

print(result)
```

Comment: Great method gsi-frank. I went with the one-liner below for simplicity